# UK passport and immigration

Tags: united-kingdom, children, nationality

I have a British passort which was obtained afer the birth of my son who is now 5 years old. So I had an indefinite leave to remain when I gave birth to him in Ghana. He lives in Ghana.

Can I apply for a British passort for him in the UK or in Ghana?

Comment: What nationality did you have when your son was born?

Comment: I had a Ghana passport but did my naturalisation a year and 5 months after he was born.n after 3mnths got my passport

Comment: Were you not able to apply for your son to become a UK citizen at the same time you did?  Were you married when you became a UK citizen?  Are you married now, and if so what is (and was) your wife's nationality?  When your son was born in Ghana, were you regularly residing in the UK or in Ghana?  Where do you live currently (and do your son and wife also live there)?

Comment: I was married but not to my son 's mother. The  mother of my child is a Ghanaian. My child live in Ghana now.I have never tried to apply for him because when he was born I only had idefinite stay

Answer (score 3):

The form that seems relevant to your case is here: https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/application-to-register-child-under-18-as-british-citizen-form-mn1

Unfortunately it is not so clear if you will be successful in your application.  But it does appear possible to try.  You'd be relying on the discretion of the British Home Secretary because your child does not appear to qualify under any of the specific rules.

Some things that might impact the decision:

- Whether you live in the UK presently, with your son, and for how long.
- Whether your wife is also a UK citizen now, and living in the UK with you.
- Whether you intend to remain in the UK.

Answer (score 2):

In response to the question, you have become a British national after the birth of your child, so it cannot be simply passed on. British nationality is not retrospective; therefore only the child may be able to apply for indefinite leave to remain but this would be an issue depending on whether the mother is going to return to the UK. To be honest, it is better you get some specialist help.

Normally those children who wish to register must be free from immigration control and at the moment, I believe your child may not have an entitlement to register as a British national.